# Windows 11 Snap Layout over a button in WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, wndproc

Is it possible to show Windows 11 Snap Layout over a button in WinForm?
I can show it over any window edge, using WM_NCHITTEST message, but I don't know how to show the Snap Layout dialog over a button in the form

Kind regards